# I need to remove the loop that comes on the final output of my Javascript program

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, settimeout, addeventlistener

I am writing a program that can detect the number of words that a user can type in certain seconds or minutes. I am new to javascript and my understanding basic. The issue here is that after the number of words is successfully calculated, the 'time limit exceeded' warning displays in loop and equal in no to the number of words typed. Same thing happens to the final result output that displays in the console. So definitely, the loop is tied to the number of inputs. Please help out

I have tried switching the codes, changing the positions and done research on the cause of the loop, but I seem stuck and decide to try out stackoverflow

Javascript script code:

```
    let no_of_words =''

const input_box = document.getElementById('input_box')
const input_para = document.getElementById('input_para')
const input_submit = document.getElementById('input_submit')


function input_result() {
  const info = document.createElement('p')
  info.textContent ='You have exceeded the time'
  info.style.color ='red'
  input_para.appendChild(info)
  //console.log(boxer);
  no_of_words = boxer.length;
  console.log(`You succesfully typed ${no_of_words} words in 10 seconds`);

}

function lock_input(){
  input_box.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  input_result()

}



const boxer =[]



input_box.addEventListener('keydown', (event)=>{
  setTimeout(lock_input, 3000);
  //console.log(`You pressed "${event.key}".`)
  boxer.push(event.key)
  

});
```

HTML code:

```
 <input type="textbox" id="input_box">
<input type="submit" id="input_submit">

<p id="input_para"></p>
```

Comment: ...and you'll stuck here too since we cannot help you without looking at your code.

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is my first time using Stacks. Was expecting another screen to input codes and it got submitted. But have done the edits already

Comment: @CBroe I didn't understand my code then. I wasn't expecting such result. I wanted the input_result to be called after  3 seconds elapses.

Comment: Every time a key is pressed, you make it executes `lock_input` three seconds later. That in turn calls `input_result`, which creates & appends a new info message element each time. Are those three seconds supposed to be the overall time the user gets to make their input? Then you should probably do this _once_, when the input field receives focus - and not on _every_ keydown.

Comment: @CBroe Yes that's what i wanted; the seconds is the overall time. I guess i should swap the 'keydown' with what now? 'focus'?

Comment: No, you will still need a keydown handler to populate your `boxer` array. (Into which you are sticking each individual key that was pressed - and then you call the number of elements that contains the _word_ count, apparently? Doesn't make too much sense either. Letters are not words.)

Comment: `You succesfully typed ${no_of_words} words in 10 seconds` - also doesn't match with your _three_ second timeout.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the corrections. Made those errors when i was tasting different solutions. And yes, I was aiming for words per time but ended up coding for character per time, which is still good, i will work on wpm later. I also followed your advice and tried to make something out. The solution I got seem better. I will display it below

Answer (score 0):

this is good to go!

```
let no_of_words ='';
const input_box = document.getElementById('input_box')
const input_para = document.getElementById('input_para')
const input_submit = document.getElementById('input_submit')


function input_result() {
  const info = document.createElement('p')
  info.textContent ='You have exceeded the time'
  info.style.color ='red'
  input_para.appendChild(info)
  //console.log(boxer);
  no_of_words = boxer.length;
  console.log(`You succesfully typed ${no_of_words.lenght} words in 10 seconds`);

}

function lock_input(){
  input_box.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  input_result()

}
const boxer =[]

var a = input_box.addEventListener('keydown', (event)=>{
   boxer.push(event.key)
    lock_input();
});


setTimeout(a, 200);
```

Comment: it executes one time.

Comment: it doesn't work. On loading the pages, it goes to final_result after 3 seconds even if i do nothing. And if i try the type into the box, it fires the final_input instantly

Comment: @Gospel367 i make a change for eventListener! Thinking this is what you want

Comment: thank you. it looks direct and i just learnt something on placement of the setTimeout function from your comment. However, the code still doesnt run good as just one (single) input fires the final_result function.

Answer (score 0):

So based on things pointed out to me by @CBroe, I was able to find the solution below. I don't know if it is a perfect one, but it works for now...

EDITED JAVASCRIPT SCRIPT

```
<pre> 
   let no_of_words =''

const input_box = document.getElementById('input_box')
const input_para = document.getElementById('input_para')
const input_submit = document.getElementById('input_submit')


function input_result() {
  const info = document.createElement('p')
  info.textContent ='You have exceeded the time'
  info.style.color ='red'
  input_para.appendChild(info)
  console.log(boxer);
  no_of_words = boxer.length;
  console.log(`You succesfully typed ${no_of_words} words in 10 seconds`);

}

function lock_input(){
  input_box.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  input_result()

}



const boxer =[]


//This is the place I made edits. Added focus event 
//and enclosed keydown event
input_box.addEventListener('focus', (event)=>{
  setTimeout(lock_input, 10000);
  //console.log(`You pressed "${event.key}".`)
  input_box.addEventListener('keydown', (event)=>{
    boxer.push(event.key)
  })  

}); </pre>
```